# How to get image data from <img> tag in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

.php file returns image file which in desktop browser is proposed to save with dialog in `UIWebView` just shows image on the page. HTML source code is as follows:

```
<html>
   <body style="margin: 0px;">
       <img style="-webkit-user-select: none" 
              src="http://www.freestockphotos.biz/download_small.php">
   </body>
</html>
```

Trying to do with js script like:

```
"var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');"
"canvas.width = img.width;"
"canvas.height = img.height;"
"var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');"
"ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);"
"var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();"
```

and `canvas.toDataURL()` throughs security error

> SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18

**SOLUTION:** Extract `NSURLRequest` from `UIWebView` and download image with some downloader (your own `NSURLConnection` based class or `AFNetworking` or other) by extracted request (it has POST params which transmitted with .php file request to get proper image).
Couldn't find way to extract image directly from `UIWebView`.

Comment: Please post an answer and accept it, so the subject is marked "solved". Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Extract `NSURLRequest` from `UIWebView` and download image with some downloader (your own `NSURLConnection` based class or `AFNetworking` or other) by extracted request (it has POST params which transmitted with .php file request to get proper image). Couldn't find way to extract image directly from `UIWebView`.